# Problem with github workflow installing package from repo using branch

Tags: github-actions

I'm struggling with authentication and getting a GitHub workflow installing a, non-published, package from another GitHub repo (under the same org). I'm specifying a branch to use with this type of dependency:

`"@organisation/repo": "https://github.com/organisation/repo#version/branch"`

This works fine locally using no npm `links`. But I get authorisation errors in a workflow with any GH token I try like so:

```
jobs:
  build:
    name: Repo checks
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js 18.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'
      - run: npm install
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GH_REPOS}}
```

Is this cross-repo access possible using tokens, or should I be authenticating differently?

Comment: Nevermind, I released a version of the package with a required fix. I had been intending to not release a version because it was off an old branch, but it's still neat enough to do it this way.